# Version number in pyinstaller and application

Tags: python, version, pyinstaller

I have an application that I want to include some version information within, and only have it defined in one location. I am running on Windows, so want to set the executable version resource, and am using pyinstaller to build the executable, but also want to be able to access the version infomration within the application itself.

So far I have followed the same kind of path that I could achieve in C - create a header with the values, include that header in both the application code and resource script, and then be able use use the single definition from the preprocessor symbol. I thought I could do something similar in python.

So far I have created a version_info.py file with the values for the version numbers:

```
MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR = 4
MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR = 2
MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_PATCH = 0
MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_BUILD = 0
```

I can then include that in my application source code no problem (cut down for brevity as this is not the issue):

```
import version_info
print(f'{version_info.MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR}.{version_info.MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR}.{version_info.MYAPPLICATION_VERSION_PATCH}')
```

I can use a 'file_version_info' type file with hardcoded values and it works OK to include the Windows version resource.

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx

VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    # filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
    # Set not needed items to zero 0.
    filevers=(1, 2, 0, 0),
    prodvers=(1, 2, 0, 0),
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'r
    mask=0x3f,
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
    flags=0x0,
    # The operating system for which this file was designed.
    # 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
    OS=0x4,
    # The general type of file.
    # 0x1 - the file is an application.
    fileType=0x1,
    # The function of the file.
    # 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
    subtype=0x0,
    # Creation date and time stamp.
    date=(0, 0)
    ),
  kids=[
    StringFileInfo(
      [
      StringTable(
        '080904b0', # 0809 = en-GB, 04b0 = Unicode
        [StringStruct('CompanyName', 'My company'),
        StringStruct('FileDescription', 'Application file description.'),
        StringStruct('FileVersion', '1.2.0.0'),
        StringStruct('InternalName', 'MyApplication.exe'),
        StringStruct('LegalCopyright', 'Copyright (C) 2021-2023 My Company, All rights reserved.'),
        StringStruct('OriginalFilename', 'MyApplication.exe'),
        StringStruct('ProductName', 'My product'),
        StringStruct('ProductVersion', '1.2.0.0')])
      ]), 
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct('Translation', [0x0809, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

I have a pyinstaller spec file for my application that pulls in a version information definition to set the Windows version details:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['MyApplication/main.py'],
    pathex=['MyApplication'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['sqlite', 'tbb'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
splash = Splash(
    'splash.png',
    binaries=a.binaries,
    datas=a.datas,
    text_pos=None,
    text_size=12,
    minify_script=True,
    always_on_top=False,
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    splash,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='MyApplication',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    version='MyApplication/file_version_info.py',
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    splash.binaries,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='MyApplication',
)
```

The problem I have is when I try to use the version number definitions in the `file_version_info` file for the pyinstaller spec file. I cannot figure out how to include those definitions and use them. I have tried variations of import, and found out that pyinstaller uses `eval()` for the version information so the closest I got was:

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx

exec("import version_info")

VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    # filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
    # Set not needed items to zero 0.
    filevers=(1, 2, 0, 0),
    prodvers=(1, 2, 0, 0),
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'r
    mask=0x3f,
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
    flags=0x0,
    # The operating system for which this file was designed.
    # 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
    OS=0x4,
    # The general type of file.
    # 0x1 - the file is an application.
    fileType=0x1,
    # The function of the file.
    # 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
    subtype=0x0,
    # Creation date and time stamp.
    date=(0, 0)
    ),
  kids=[
    StringFileInfo(
      [
      StringTable(
        '080904b0', # 0809 = en-GB, 04b0 = Unicode
        [StringStruct('CompanyName', 'My company'),
        StringStruct('FileDescription', 'Application file description.'),
        StringStruct('FileVersion', '1.2.0.0'),
        StringStruct('InternalName', 'MyApplication.exe'),
        StringStruct('LegalCopyright', 'Copyright (C) 2021-2023 My Company, All rights reserved.'),
        StringStruct('OriginalFilename', 'MyApplication.exe'),
        StringStruct('ProductName', 'My product'),
        StringStruct('ProductVersion', '1.2.0.0')])
      ]), 
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct('Translation', [0x0809, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

But in this case I ultimately get the error:

```
  File "<string>", line 8
    VSVersionInfo(
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which seems odd to me because I can perform an `eval('exec("import version_info.py")')` on the command line and it is OK.

So my question is: how do I define the version number in a single place that the python code and pyinstaller version resource can use that common definition.

Comment: Apolgies to anyone who looked at the original question, I forgot to remove some of the company information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not being able to use `exec("import version_info")` within the file_version_info file and getting a SyntaxError was because of the way pyinstaller uses the file. It reads the contents of the file into a string and then calls `vs = eval(txt)`. So the contents of the file must make for a valid syntax when considering the assignment, which the `exec()` call broke.

The solution I ended up using was to define the version fields in a standalone python source that I can import from my code, and also wrote a simple python source to generate the `file_version_info` file using those values. When I build my executable I use a shell script to run the `file_version_info` generator immediately before running pyinstaller.

Another option I could have resorted to was to read the version information from within the exe at runtime from my code. However, I did not want to use this method as the version information would not be present when debugging.